# Journey blog engine written in Go (content/themes/[theme] #Error)

Tags: go, ghost-blog, blog-engine, journey

*After a lot of attempts I am still getting a crash on journey blog engine (journey-windows-386)... I tried different themes supported by this platform.
The only one that works is the default one [promenade]!*

**Check the log files as reference :** http://txt.do/d129y

Comment: You should post the error here, and a minimal example of what you've attempted. Else, I'd suggest raising an issue on the project itself. the blog engine appears to have a bug or error. Are you running the latest version?

Comment: Nothing more than changing the default theme...after that I am getting the crash and the error in log file! yes I am running the latest version!